# useEffect is now working when dependency is empty array

Tags: reactjs

I have below code.

when `perioddata`'s state changes, it runs the first useEffect with dependency [perioddata].

In there, it updates `resultData` state.

After resultData updates, it runs the second useEffect with dependency [resultdata].

```
  const [perioddata, setPerioddata] = useState([]);
  const [resultData, setResultData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("perioddata", perioddata);
    let resultdata = resultDateFunc(perioddata);
    setResultData(resultdata);
  }, [perioddata]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("resultdata", resultData);
  }, [resultData]);
```

At first it runs well.

When I console.log all these, it shows correct each data.

```
perioddata (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
resultdata (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Later, I change `perioddata` and it becomes empty array.

when it becomes empty array, as I think, since perioddata's state changes -> resultdata updates and it should run the second useEffect.

However, the second useEffect doesn't run.

console shows only empty perioddata only.

```
perioddata []
```

Do you know why the second useEffect doesn't run in this case?

Comment: What does the resultDateFunc do? If the reference of resultData is not changing then the effect will not run.

Comment: How are you changing perioddata? If it is unexpectedly changing to an empty array, you need to investigate that first

Comment: I try to reproduce this  and only time I get this result is when resultDateFunc function doesn't return anything. So check that I think that might b the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to modify `resultData` separately, the pattern where you use `useEffect` to directly derive some state from other data, i.e.

```
const [perioddata, setPerioddata] = useState([]);
const [resultData, setResultData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  let resultdata = resultDateFunc(perioddata);
  setResultData(resultdata);
}, [perioddata]);
```

should just be replaced with `useMemo`:

```
const [perioddata, setPerioddata] = useState([]);
const resultData = useMemo(() => resultDateFunc(perioddata), [perioddata]);
```

Comment: still it shows perioddata only

Comment: What shows? There's no `console.log` here (and there shouldn't be).